# Xamarin Forms - Slider Thumb border color

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm facing an issue with my Slider with dynamic ThumbColor :

```
<Slider ValueChanged="Handle_ValueChanged" MaximumTrackColor="{StaticResource Grey}" MinimumTrackColor="{StaticResource DarkGrey}" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" ThumbColor="{Binding ThumbColor}" Value="{Binding ColorValue}" />
```

The binding in ThumbColor can have multiple color, but for once, the color if the same of the background :

When is OK :

[image]

When is NOK :

[image]

Facing to design guidelines, it will be hard to change the background color.
And the white thumb color comes from backend data.

So if anyone knows have a solution to see the white one.

Comment: Create a custom renderer that adds a drop shadow or an alternative (black?) outer ring color to the thumb in order for it to be visible.

Comment: Is what i am looking for, but I did not found any documentation or tutorial to do it :(

Comment: ? Keep the custom renderer and the iOS UISlider (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider?language=objc) as separate steps, first create an iOS playground (using Xamarin Workbooks is great for this : https://developer.xamarin.com/workbooks/) to work out the UISlider details and once done with that, migrate that code into a custom renderer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: Thanks I will try to add the shadow :)